# Electric field of an infinitely long (thin) metal cylinder

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics

An infinitely long thin metal cylinder of radius $a$ coaxial with the $z$ axis carries a uniform surface charge density $\sigma=\frac{\lambda}{2\pi a}$, where $\lambda$ is a constant. A thick cylindrical insulating tube coaxial with the metal cylinder carries a uniform volume charge density $\rho=\frac{\lambda}{\pi(c^2-b^2)}$ throughout its volume. The insulating cylindrical tube has an inner radius $b$ and an outer radius $c$. Find the electric when a. $$s<a$$ b.$$a<s<b$$ c.$$b<s<c$$ d.$$s>c$$

So we'd have to use Gauss's law for each case, varying the width of the Gaussian surface.

Comment: That is indeed what you should do. Is there even a question here?

Comment: I'm just not sure how/where to start because the charge densities vary. I would integrate them across the different boundaries, yes?

Answer (score 2):

Okay, since the problem is cylindrically symmetric, you should take a cylindrical Gaussian surface. The left and right sides of the cylinder are parallel to the field--which points radially outward like the other piece of the surface. 
$$\oint\limits_{S}\vec{E}\cdot\mbox{d}\vec{a}=\frac{1}{\epsilon_0}\int\limits_{V}\rho\ \mbox{d}V$$

now reduces to $$2\pi sE=\frac{1}{\epsilon_0}\int\limits_V\rho\ \mbox{d}V$$

Now, you need to find the charge density inside each volume of interest, and integrate it over the relevant volume/surface (wherever the charge is confined). You can add up contributions from surface charges and volume charges separately.